# delete blocks of text from a string based on a pattern in them

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have a big string that is a combination of many blocks (chunks) of data:

> {Hello user, good morning \br}{Welcome user, this is just a static
>   text, continue to next page}{Hope you are doing well \br enjoy your
>   stay here.}

What i would like to do is, to remove the chunks from it, that contain a specific character set: `\br`.

So the above string should be:

> {Welcome user, this is just a static text, continue to next page}

I have tried preg_replace, without luck:

```
$a = "{Hello user, good morning \br}{Welcome user, this is just a static text \br continue to next page}{Hope you are doing well \br enjoy your stay here.}";
$b = preg_replace('/\s+\br\s+/', "", $a);
print $b;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`$b = preg_replace('/{[^{]*\\br.*?}/', "", $a);`

Breaking that into chunks:

- `{` searches for a { character
- `[^{]*` means "match any character that isn't a { any number of times (after all, if we find another { it means we're starting a new block. You could also use })
- `?` makes the previous match non-greedy, meaning we'll get the smallest group possible
- `\\br` will match \br
- `.*?` is a non-greedy match that will match anything that comes before...
- `}` the closing brace

Comment: Returns the same string back. Also i had to avoid **/g** in the pattern, as its not a valid modifier in PCRE PHP.

Comment: Okay, I've tried the edited version in PHP and it seems fine.

Comment: This is working well for a small string, but when i have a nested string, it is not giving proper result. Example string that fails: *{Hello {testing 123} {another test}} {testing again}*

Comment: You mean when that if you change the question the old answer is incorrect? Surprise ;-)

Comment: [This one fails](http://codepad.org/lvuCQEw2). May be i need to modify the regex further, to suit the nested string.